# Where are the NPC Pokemon traders in Pokemon Sun & Moon and which Pokemon do they offer?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

Every generation of Pokemon I try and trade with every NPC Trader in-game.

I've only just started the game, but where are the NPC Traders in Alola? What Pokemon do they offer, and what do they want in return?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [this site](https://www.google.com/amp/www.thebitbag.com/pokemon-sun-moon-game-trade-pokemon-can-get-npcs/200087/amp?client=safari), this is a list of all of the in-game trades you can make in Sun & Moon:

> Player Lillipup for NPC Bounsweet (Called Bouncee)

- In the Pokémon Center before the Lana's Trial (Route 5, near Brooklet Hill)

> Player Zubat for NPC Poliwhirl (Called Whirly)

- In the Pokémon Center in Konikoni City.

> Player Pancham for NPC Happiny (Called Happini)

- In the Sushi High Roller in Maile City.

> Player Haunter for NPC Graveler

- In the Pokémon Center closest to the Aether House.

> Player Granbull for NPC Steenee (Called Stena)

- In Seafolk Village, on the docks.

> Player Bewear for NPC Talonflame (Called Talo)

- Just before the entrance to the Battle Tree in Poni Gauntlet.

> Player Spearow for NPC Machop
>   **Nickname:** Macho
>   **Ability:** No Guard
>   **Nature:** Brave
>   **Held Item:** X Attack

- In the Pokémon Center on Route 2.

<sub>(Locations provided from [Serebii](http://www.serebii.net/sunmoon/ingametrades.shtml))</sub>

Comment: At the moment, locations haven't been found. I'll update this answer once they have been, but this seems to be the complete list of traders in the game.

Comment: Cool. I'll wait for locations before accepting :)

Comment: @Robotnik fair enough. I'm keeping an eye out!